# Is there any middleware library like PassportJS for Fastify?

Tags: node.js, express, oauth, passport.js, fastify

I was experimenting with NestJS and Fastify as an underlying HTTP framework but soon ran into a problem when tried implementing an OAuth for Google signup. Since PassportJS has been my goto library for this purpose, I thought it would work here too. Later realized that PassportJS is only compatible with Express-based web apps.

Is there a way to make PassportJS work with Fastify or a good alternate for it?

Comment: still working for the [official plugin](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-passport/pull/3)

Comment: @ManuelSpigolon I saw that, the reason why I am looking for an alternative. Anyway, hoping for the PR to be merged soon

Comment: I don't know if [fastify-oauth2](https://github.com/fastify/fastify-oauth2/) has all the features you are looking for, but it implement the oauth2 flow